# Strip newline and white spaces from Python Logger messages

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to setup a logger formatter that strips any leading '\n' or '\t' characters before displaying the message.

Is there a way to do this by setting up a logger filter?

EDIT: I understand I should str.strip(), but how can I integrate this with the logger for every message?

Here's an example of my logger setup:

```
def initialize_logging(log_dir='Logs', log_name='log.log',
                   console_level='INFO', file_level='DEBUG'):
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    start_time_string= start_time.strftime("%m-%d-%y_%Hh%Mm%Ss")

    if file_level == "DEBUG":
        level = logging.DEBUG
    elif file_level == "INFO":
        level = logging.INFO
    elif file_level == "WARNING":
        level = logging.WARNING
    elif file_level == "ERROR":
        level = logging.ERROR
    elif file_level == "CRITICAL":
        level = logging.CRITICAL
    else:
        level = logging.INFO

    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.setLevel(level)

    #create a log formatter
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-24s: %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s','%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S')

    #create log handlers

    #console handler
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    if console_level == "DEBUG":
        console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    elif console_level == "INFO":
        console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    elif console_level == "WARNING":
        console.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    elif console_level == "ERROR":
        console.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    elif console_level == "CRITICAL":
        console.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
    else:
        console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(console)

    log_path = str(os.getcwd()) + '/Logs/'
    if not os.path.exists(log_path):
        os.makedirs(log_path)

    log_file_name = 'last.log'
    log_file = os.path.join(log_path, log_file_name)

    logfile = logging.FileHandler(log_file, "w")
    if file_level == "DEBUG":
        logfile.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    elif file_level == "INFO":
        logfile.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    elif file_level == "WARNING":
        logfile.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    elif file_level == "ERROR":
        logfile.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    elif file_level == "CRITICAL":
        logfile.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
    else:
        logfile.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logfile.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(logfile)

    return log #return a path to the log file
```

Comment: The formatter line looks like the critical part of your log message.  Try formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-24s: %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s','%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S').strip()

Comment: Formatter doesnt have a strip() method. This will not work.

Answer (score 14):

Because you're modifying the input message itself, you need to subclass `logging.Formatter`

```
class WhitespaceRemovingFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        record.msg = record.msg.strip()
        return super(WhitespaceRemovingFormatter, self).format(record)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def logger(my_str):
    s = my_str.strip()
    print s

logger("\n\ttest")
```

From the docs:

```
string.strip(s[, chars])
```

`Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters in the string will be stripped from the both ends of the string this method is called on.`

Answer (score -2):

Use [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method:

```
>>> s= "\n\rrohit\n"
>>> s.strip()
'rohit'
```

Comment: How can I integrate this with the logger for every message though?

Comment: You might want to post some sample code of your logger if you want suggestions on how to implement it with your current code..